# How to store text from webpage to alias, then use that same alias as typing to a textbox

Tags: cypress, alias

I have this kind of idea how to create a alias, I guess that should be correct, at least page contains that data-cy that I'm looking for.

Issue seems to be that these are two different tests and therefore alias doesn't "survive". Is there anything to be done, to use alias on a second case?

```
       // copy activation code
                cy.get('[data-cy="activation-code-guidance"]>strong').as('activationCode')
                });
```

Next I have pop-up window which has textbox for that activationcode we got on a previous step.

I have tried different kind of things in order to get that alias value typed to that box, no success. Almost every example is for comparing values, or values that are hardcoded.

Must say that I'm far from pro with this, this will be my first test, but I'm willing to learn

Here are some examples I have tried

```
        const activationCodeInput = () => cy.get('[name=undefined]');
                activationCodeInput().type(cy.get('@activationCode'));
```

other one

```
cy.get('@activationCode').then(activationCodeText => 
                console.log(activationCodeText))
                cy.get('[name=undefined]').type(activationCodeText);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second code block is correct in theory:

```js
cy.get('@activationCode').then(activationCodeText => {
  cy.get('[name=undefined]').type(activationCodeText)
})
```

You should try adding `type:static` option to the alias in case the value is changing before you use it.

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="activation-code-guidance"]>strong')
  .as('activationCode', {type:static})
```

Also, `cy.get('[name=undefined]')` is suspicious. Try looking for a better selector, you can't search for something that isn't there.

I doubt that the `<input>` you want to type into has a `name` attribute of `"undefined"`. In other words, it's unlikely to be `<input name="undefined">`.

Answer (score 0):

Storing Cypress yields in aliases does not give you the value or text of the element, but instead gives you a `Chainable<T>`. In cases where you're aliasing a `cy.get()` on an element, this is most likely `Chainable<JQueryHTMLElement>`.

So, trying to do `cy.get('foo').type(cy.get('@myAlias'))` won't type the value of `myAlias`.

Instead, we can store the text or value of the element, and use that to enter a value.

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="activation-code-guidance"]>strong')
  .invoke('text') // change subject to the text value of the element
  .as('activationCode')
...
cy.get('@activationCode').then((activationCode) => {
  cy.get('[name=undefined]').type(activationCode)
});
```

Or, if we wanted to store the element directly, we can do that and then use JQuery's `.text()` function to retrieve the text. However, we'll need to make sure that Cypress can still find the element if we are storing it. If you've scrolled away, navigated to another page, or the element is being covered up, there is a chance this can fail.

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="activation-code-guidance"]>strong')
  .as('activationCode');
...
cy.get('@activationCode').then((activationCode) => {
  cy.get('[name=undefined]').type(activationCode.text());
});
```

Comment: Noe of these worked